# What is the correct and best way to deploy jhipster applications (registry, gateway and a microservice) to AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jhipster

If I see JHipster production Deploy to AWS instructions, it looks like I will have to execute jhipster aws commands under each application (gateway, microservice, registry).
Is that so? Won't it consume/provision too much resoirces on AWS?

What if I want to deploy all 3 (rgistry, gateway and microservice) on single instance, and so is database (single DB server for bpth gateway and microservice)

Please guide!

Answer (score 0):

`jhipster aws`'s goal is to deploy easily with reasonable choices in terms of production reliability.

In your case, you want to optimize costs and are ready to make some compromises on reliability and performance, you'll have to do it using AWS tools (CloudFormation or AWS CDK).

The choices are yours, there is no such thing as a "best way".

Comment: Thanks @gaël-marziou You are the only one always answering my JHipster questions :)

Comment: But @gaël-marziou could you please clarify, can't we use jhipster aws command in a way so to use the same resources for applications and databases for one single project?

Comment: Not really, it works per application. The aws sub generator uses the AWS SDK, so you could have a look at its code and modify it but it should be easier to learn how to do the same using AWS CDK and reading project information from .yo-rc.json file.